# symplectic groups in GAP

Tags: finite-groups, gap

For the symplectic groups in GAP : `grp:=SymplecticGroup(n,q)`, what is the underlying metric or bilinear form ($M$)?
For example if I use `A:=Random(grp)` to get a random symplectic matrix this matrix should satisfy $A^\dagger A=1$ where $A^\dagger=M A^t M^{-1}$; what is $M$? I tried $[[0,-I],[I,0]]$ but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the manual (https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap50.html#X8674AAA578FE4AEE), the form is stored in the `InvariantBilinearForm` attribute (as entry `.matrix`):

```
gap> grp:=SP(4,5);;
gap> M:=InvariantBilinearForm(grp).matrix;;
gap> Display(M);
 . . . 1
 . . 1 .
 . 4 . .
 4 . . .
gap> List(GeneratorsOfGroup(grp),x->TransposedMat(x)*M*x=M);
[ true, true ]
```

Comment: Thanks; that answers the question. Curious about the choice of this particular form; it's different from the more "traditional"  : $I_n \otimes [[0,1],[-1,0]]$ or $[[0,1],[-1,0]] \otimes I_n$;

Comment: It is often arguable what choice is the ``standard''. However here the choice of form stems from the construction of the groups as Chevalley groups (https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/don/papers/genAC.pdf) -- the choice is made to write matrix generators nicely, and the form then is taken.